# Access user's first name and other information in firebase using Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building my first ever IOS app with the help of online resources. I was able to build the signup and login screens of the app and connect it to firebase and store user's information on there. However, I want to get (retrieve) user's first name from the database when they log in and display that, and I found a piece of code that successfully does that but it is very slow, everything else in the page loads before it, so it is not really an ideal solution. I was wondering if there was another way to achieve what I want to do.

Code that checks if user's is signed in and gets its first name:

```
func CheckIfUserIsSignedIn() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    if let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        let userName = db.collection("users").getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                self.errorLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
                self.errorLabel.text = "Error getting documents: \(error)"
            }
            else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    if let firstUserDoc = snapshot?.documents.first {
                       let welcomeName = firstUserDoc["first_name"] as! String
                       self.errorLabel.text = "Hey, \(welcomeName) welcome!"
                    }
                }
            } //end else
        }
    } //end if
    else {
        //User is not logged in
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "login")
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
} //end CheckIfUserIsSignedIn method`
```

Comment: Search for asynchroneous and Firebase.

Comment: Welcome to Firebase. Naming your vars accurately will help debug later. So this `userName = db.collection("users").getDocuments()` does not return a userName - in fact `let userName` can be removed as it's not needed. You can access the returned documents within the closure following the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this but just one thing I want to point out is that when you check if the user has logged in with `if let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` you then proceed to retrieve every user document with `let userName = db.collection("users").getDocuments()` which is probably making it much more slower than it needs to be. And this will get slower the more popular your app becomes because downloading more users takes more time. This is an easy fix by just adding one small thing:

`let userName = db.collection("users").document(userId).getDocument()`
This only gets 1 document instead of all.

Also right after that you loop through each document you've retrieved and perform

```
if let firstUserDoc = snapshot?.documents.first {
    let welcomeName = firstUserDoc["first_name"] as! String
    self.errorLabel.text = "Hey, \(welcomeName) welcome!"
}
```

This block is run `snapshot!.documents.count` (Number of users you have in your app) amount of times which again seems unnecessary as it does the same thing each iteration. Remove the loop and doing it 1 time will be so much faster.

This is how your code should look after:

```
if let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
    db.collection("users").document(userId).getDocument { docSnapshot, error in
        if let error = error {
            errorLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            errorLabel.text = "Error getting documents: \(error)"
        } else {
            let welcomeName = docSnapshot!.get("first_name") as! String
            errorLabel.text = "Hey, \(welcomeName) welcome!"
        }
    }
} //end if
// ...Other code
```

This should work but if you want an even faster way to do this and don't use the `Auth.auth().currentUser!.displayName` property then you can store their first name in that and simply reduce your code to:

```
if let userFirstName = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName! {
    errorLabel.text = "Hey, \(userFirstName) welcome!"
} else {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "login")
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

^ This would be ideal if your app refers to all users by their first names instead of their usernames (plus it'll show up in verification emails as well)

One last thing I'd like to mention is in your original post I don't understand how you were guaranteeing the first document of the snapshot to be the user you want. If it's an old user using the app then someone else's name would probably come up as newer users will be at the top of the list. As this is your first app I want to stress the importance of writing tests for your functions. Be sure to read up on **Unit Tests** and **UI Tests** (mainly Unit Tests for your purposes), they really make a big difference. It's not too hard to learn either. I remember when I first started I avoided them like the plague because I thought they took too much time. But in the long run they save you thousands of hours by making your code as bug free as possible and even help structuring your code better by making it more modular!

Hope this helps and best of luck with your first app!